# Making the nested div to extent to the height of the main div

Tags: html

I am trying for a or b to to match their height when one or the other one extends.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
     #main{
     width:300px;
     position: relative;
     margin: 0 auto;
     }
     #a{
     position:absolute:
     bottom:0px;
     width:50px;
     border: 1px solid #000;
     float:left;
     }
     #b{
      position:absolute:
     bottom:0px;
      width:200px;
      border: 1px solid #000;
      float:left;
     }

    </style>

    <body>
     <div id="main">
    <div id='a'><h1>1</ht><h1>1</ht><h1>1</ht><h1>1</ht></div>
    <div id='b'>2</div>
     </div></div></head></body>
```

Comment: He's got one too many </div> tags right before </head>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a very simple solution. Use css attribute `display: table-cell;` in `.a{}` & `.b{}` style like this:

```
    .a, .b{ 

         display: table-cell;
         width:100px; 
         vertical-align:middle; 
         text-align:center;

     }
```

See the Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/qcCPG/6/